# Bernoulli's Equation - Doubt

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, bernoulli-equation

Ok so we have this question:

> [image]

Now when I take these two points:

> [image]

Applying bernoulli's equation to these points: taking Pressure at point 1(inside the beaker) to be $P_o$ + $\rho gd$ , and second pressure as $P_o$ , and the velocities as 0 and v , and taking any datum level (since change in P.E.going to stay constant), I am not getting the correct answer , which is √2gy.... I checked the solution and it involves taking the point on the surface of the liquid as the other point... could anybody tell why my method is wrong? Why do we have to take both the pressures as equal.

Comment: Some things are a bit unclear. You should label the points. What is point 1? At what point is the "second pressure"? What answer did you get and which steps did you take to arrive there? Hope this helps you find the answer!

Comment: Point 1 the Point B and point 2 is the point A ( Yeah sorry i should have named it as B and A from the figure only). So Second pressure - is basically the pressure at point A which is exposed to atmosphere and has P not pressure.... and also steps were directly from the  bernoulli's equation P + pgh + K.E. remains constant... I know the question I have asked requires lot fo formatting and stuff but at that moment I did not have much time so that's why the question has been ill-framed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically the following image. We know the height at all the points, so we just need to know a velocity and pressure at some more points to determine the velocity at $C$. Where do we know the pressure? At point $A$ and $C$! Why? We know that if a surface is exposed to air, it must be atmospheric pressure. If it wasn't, there would be pressure difference and a force, so the system would not be in equilibrium$^\dagger$. It is hard to say whether point $C$ is in equilibrium because water is spilling out, so I tried to draw it this way to make it a little more clear.

Since the velocity at the point $A$ is zero, we have enough information to solve the system. Define the height at point $A$ as zero, then
\begin{align}
P_A+\tfrac 1 2\rho v_A^2+\rho gh_A&=P_C+\tfrac 1 2\rho v_C^2+\rho gh_C\\
\implies P_0+0+0&=P_0+\tfrac 1 2\rho v_C^2-\rho g d_{AC}
\end{align}
where $P_0$ is atmospheric pressure and $\rho$ is the density of the water.

[image: siphon]

$\dagger$ With 'in equilibrium' I mean that the problem does not change in time. This problem is an example of hydrostatics, which only deals with 'static' configurations of fluid. This might seem confusing because the water is moving, but we define a fluid as static when all important variables such as velocity, pressure etc. do not change in time. The water level is dropping, but it is dropping slowly enough that we can neglect this.

Comment: But why can't we do this for point B? Rest answer was awesome thanks.

Comment: We can also use point $B$ of course. But we can't use the trick that it's at atmospheric pressure, because there is a layer of water between. So the pressure at $B$ would be $P_0+\rho g d_{AB}$. You can do the calculation and you would get the same answer. The only difference is that you do an unnecessary step in between. So you can use both point $A$ and $B$ as a reference, but $B$ is harder to calculate.